# How can I rewrite an already rewritten file if it is not found

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I need to rewrite a URL for an image file. This is the easy part and looks like this:

```
RewriteRule ^img[/]?(/[^.]+)?$ - [L]
RewriteRule ^img/([A-Za-z0-9_-\s]+)/([A-Za-z0-9_\-\s\.]+)?$ cache/$1-$2 [L]
```

However if the image file is not found in that cache directory I need to rewrite this again to a PHP script that will create the image and save it in that cache directory.

I tried the following rewrite, but it doesn't work as intended. Instead all image URLs are rewritten to the PHP file regardless if the file exists in the cache or not.

```
#RewriteCond cache/%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
#RewriteCond cache/%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
#RewriteRule ^cache/([A-Za-z0-9_\s]+)-([A-Za-z0-9_\-\s\.]+)?$ createimg.php?type=1&hash=$1&filename=$2 [L]
```

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: I am pretty sure you should remove `cache/` before `%{REQUEST_FILENAME}` and it will then work.

Comment: Thanks, this seems to work, but now any not-found file will be redirected to that PHP script, not just not-found cache files. I can work around that by redirecting to 404 on the PHP script, but was hoping for a more elegant solution.

Comment: Actually ignore my comment above, it will only rewrite cache files because of the Rewrite Rule... Thanks again!

Comment: I have left an answer just so you can mark the question as solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since after the first rule, the same rules will be matched with the new url, the url already contains "cache/". `%{REQUEST_FILENAME}` and other magic variables are updated accordingly. Therefore you don't need to put "cache/" in front of the variable.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^cache/([A-Za-z0-9_\s]+)-([A-Za-z0-9_\-\s\.]+)?$ createimg.php?type=1&hash=$1&filename=$2 [L]
```